# How to change font-style on strings when brackets occur (using PHP/CSS)

Tags: php, mysql, css

I'm fairly new to PHP and MySQL, but have been having a lot of fun with it in the last few months. I'm a bit stuck as to how to achieve this though, so hopefully some of you can help me out.

I have a text column in my MySQL DB that stores lines of text. I retrieve this by PHP and iterate over each line. What I want to achieve is that everything placed in these brackets; "[" and "]"  - are greyed out in another font-class (or using span-tag) by CSS when I output them. This is for displaying them in a style similar to comments. So far I've written this code to grab the string position for both brackets, but I'm stuck on how to achieve the desired effect with PHP+HTML/CSS, as the placement of the brackets differ from line to line.

```
if (isset ($row['setlist'])) 
{
    echo "Setlist:<div class='setlist'>";
    foreach(explode("\n", $row['setlist']) as $line) 
    {
        $a = strpos ($line,"["); 
        $b = strpos($line,"]"); 
        if ($a || $b > 0) 
        { 
            // how to use the position to change fontclass/color from position $a to $b..? 
        }
        echo $line."<br>";}
        echo "</div>";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace [ and ] with `<span class="greyedout">` and `</a>`, that's much easier and should do the same.